# SmartRule For HTTP

Tags: cumulocity

In the Cumulocity guide, https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/event-language/introduction/, there is a mention of Event Streams for HTTP.

> HTTP  ResponseReceived    SendReqeust This group of events represents sending http requests to external services.

This means we can send outbound HTTP request to external services using the "SendRequest" stream. However, I did not find any further details in any documentation. Can you please provide the template CEL details for SendRequest, and how to configure the same in Cumulocity?

Answer (score 0):

I can not help you using the actual engine (Apama) but I can give you one example using Esper.

```
@Name("Sending the http request")
@Resilient
insert into 
  SendRequest
select 
  'post' as method,
  'https://tenant.cumulocity.com/inventory/managedObjects' as url,
  'Basic .....' as authorization,
  'application/json' as contentType,
   toJSON(m) as body
from anyEventStream m;
```

The toJSON if a function that takes the event stream and return is equivalent in json.

You can find more info [here](https://cumulocity.com/guides/event-language/data-model/). This info is hide from the actual docs and think it is because they want to push developers to use APAMA instead ESPER.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jorge , this is really helpful. Yes I am using Esper CEP only as of now. Hence this will work for me. :)